# Which effects can I use to mask my voice in Audacity, yet keep it a plausible male voice?

Tags: audacity, voice

I'm making a voice-over for my animation, and since my voice sounds horrible, I'm embarrassed to even think that it would be reverse-engineered and heard by thousands of people on YouTube.

I'm using Audacity, applying effects: Bass and treble, Change pitch, and Reverb, which for now seem very powerful and with them I manage to maintain the voice as a plausible male voice.

Do you know perhaps which effects could I try in Audacity, apart from the 3 mentioned, to make my voice non-reverse-engineerable and yet a plausible male voice?

I thank you in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Mask implies hiding, I think you mean alter ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at processing options which alter the "Formant" of the voice. The "Formant" is the lower frequency "base" of the vocal sound. "Little Alter Boy" might be an option.

Comment: Thank you Mark, your answer has been very helpful.

Comment: Totally agree! I've made a couple of tracks where I've put on an accent and then used a formant shifter and no one can tell that it was me in the first place!